# php get_tags() to list all the tags for the products in a specific category in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, woocommerce, categories

So in woocommerce when I am looking at all the products in a specific category I have lets say 6 pages of 10 products each or 60 products total in that specific category being listed.

I'm using `$product->get_tags();` to get the tags of the products in that category to display them in a sidebar so users can filter through each tag.

The problem is `$product->get_tags();` only gets the tags of the products on the current page. I need it to get all the tags from all 60 products, not just the first ten from the first page, or let's say 11-20 on the second page.

### Example behavior:

The tags related to all the products in the category are: science, space, mythology, stars

the tags related to the products on the first page are: science, space

`echo $product->get_tags();` prints out only science and space.

I need to be able to print out all the tags: science, space, mythology, stars

but pagination is making this limited. Is there another function I could use that I am unaware of? Or maybe a loop?

Comment: Hey Chris! Did you sorted this out? Have the same issue

Comment: I did, however, I do not have the code for it anymore unfortunantly, we've moved on to a different structure since then. What I did was I queried the woocommerce table which contains every single product, and pulled the ones with matching tags. using a loop, and storing the product objects in an array. Then I looped through this object array and posted the necessary information from each object in my html. 

I hope that helps point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$tags = get_terms( 'product_tag' );`
See the function reference at [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms).

Comment: that gets every tag from every product, is there a way to pass a category argument to it?

Comment: The only solution I could think was: [see code](https://gist.github.com/luancuba/5fb4f0634821b05a6f81)